# Scrape images from tweets using R

Tags: r, blogdown

I would love to make a [twitter-blogdown](https://github.com/yihui/twitter-blogdown) blog of images that some one posts, but I'm not sure it is even possible. I used 'twitteR' to scrape all the posts from one person, but it looks like I would have to do something completely different to get images instead of text.

Any advice on what direction to take would be appreciated.

Comment: One strategy: 1. Use regular expressions to scan a status for links (e.g. `"(?i-)https?://t\\.co/[A-z0-9]+"`], 2. decode the urls (e.g. using `httr::HEAD(...)$url`), #3 check if it's a photo link, #4 open the photo links url, #5 use xpaths to grab the image url, #6 use `download.file` to finally download the image.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quite a broad question, but here are some ideas.

First: I recommend using the [rtweet](https://github.com/mkearney/rtweet) package. In my experience it makes authentication much easier and returns data in easy-to-use structures.

As an example, here's how I'd fetch my own last 100 tweets after setting up authentication as described in the package documentation:

```
library(rtweet)
library(dplyr)

neilfws <- get_timeline("neilfws", n = 100)
neilfws %>%
  glimpse()
```

The column `media_id` indicates whether a tweet has attached media, value = NA if not. So a quick count of how many rows have media:

```
neilfws %>%
  filter(!is.na(media_id) %>%
  nrow()
```

The link to the media is in the column `media_url`. So here are the first 6 images associated with my tweets:

```
neilfws %>% 
  filter(!is.na(media_id)) %>% 
  select(media_url) %>% 
  head()

1 http://pbs.twimg.com/media/DHzGbvyVoAAm8in.jpg
2 http://pbs.twimg.com/media/DHfc4idV0AA6qyc.jpg
3 http://pbs.twimg.com/media/DHfNamEVYAA5H_U.jpg
4 http://pbs.twimg.com/media/DHYuG1oUwAADV-z.jpg
5 http://pbs.twimg.com/media/DHQlEQqUAAAHoCK.jpg
6 http://pbs.twimg.com/media/DHLG_ESUMAAMURj.jpg
```

Now you have the media URLs, you can work on the code to retrieve or display them.

Comment: This was a good start, I did like `rtweet` better. Thanks to @Yihui's edit, I also found some great [steps](https://github.com/yihui/twitter-blogdown/blob/master/content/about.md) to get started on the structure.